# Nested Business Model in Devise Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, registration, nested-attributes

I'm relatively new to rails and am using devise for my user sign up and sign in processes. At sign up if a user doesn't have an invite token I would like them to also sign up and create their business that will be associated with their user account.

Below is a screenshot of the error I am getting in my RegistrationsController when trying to create the new business.

[image: NoMethodError in RegistrationsController]

Here is my code in the registrations_controller.rb:

```
if params[:invite_code]
    ...
else
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.businesses.build()  # Inserts a blank object for business
    respond_with resource
end
```

Any ideas on why it isn't able to pass the business information provided and create a new business? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Rails thinks `businesses` is an array, when `build` works on an association. Does your user model have a `has_many` or is `businesses` a serialized array? If the former, you may be missing the `has_many` line in your user model. If the latter, `build` is not what you want, but instead `businesses.push(business_params)`.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could put your full controller, model and view into a gist and link to it.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz and here is the gist containing my controller, models and view. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc1eabdcfedb74bbca2b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a pluralization issue. The `has_one` association on the `User` should be singular (`:business`) as should the method call in the controller (`resource.business.build()`) and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

That being said, that part of the controller should never even be getting hit. All of your logic should be contained within this [first conditional](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc1eabdcfedb74bbca2b#file-registrations_controller-rb-L10-L29). Everything happening [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc1eabdcfedb74bbca2b#file-registrations_controller-rb-L32-L51) should probably be pulled out into another method and called after the successful `save`. Here's a new gist with a refactoring of `registrations_controller.rb`: https://gist.github.com/ccschmitz/7ea0a41180e25de9168d

Comment: I'm confused... using the controller that you refactored still doesn't save the new business the user is creating, only their account.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` needs to be singular as well. I've updated my answer - let me know if that helps!